# Upper bound for the expectation of E$(e^\frac{c}{N+1})$ where N is a binomial distribution and $c$ is constant

Tags: probability

Let $N\sim \text{Binom}(n,p)$, and $c>0$.

How can I compute an upper bound for the following expression?

$$ \text{E}\left(e^\frac{c}{N+1}\right) $$

I want the upper bound to be close as possible to lower bound driven by Jensen's inequality , i.e., close to:
$$ e^\frac{c}{np+1} $$

What I have tried:

1. Compute the direct sum. Does not seems to help.
2. Using that  $e^X=1+X+\frac{X^2}{2}+...$ with the moments of the
   inverse binomial distribution does not seems to provide an upper
   bound.
3. Used Chernoff and Hoeffding's inequalities to bound the minimal value of $N$ and bound the expectation using law of expectations (see  @Sangchul Lee
   comment). The bounds are very far from the lower bound.

Comment: Have you tried a direct calculation?

Comment: Yes. Got a sum of multiple elements, not a simple upper bound

Comment: The [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) gives a simple upper bound of the form $$\mathbb{E}[e^{\frac{c}{N+1}}] \leq e^{-2\varepsilon^2 n} + e^{\frac{c}{(p-\varepsilon)n + 1}} $$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. Perhaps you may play with $\varepsilon$ to optimize this upper bound.

Comment: @SangchulLee How does your written inequality is driven from Hoeffding's inequality?

Comment: I mean, I got from the law of expectations that  $e^{-2\epsilon^2n}$ should be multiplied by $e^c$

Comment: You are right, I forgot to multiply that factor :s Thank you for pointing out my mistake!